# Print String elements in a list in order

Tags: java, webdriver

I am getting a list of Strings from a webpage using Selenium Webdriver.  I then want to assert that they match the corresponding list from the relevant API.  However, the method I am using currently seems to order them randomly.  Is there a better solution that allows me to order them as they appear on the page?

```
    List<WebElement> props;
    props = driver.findElements(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='day1']//*[contains(@id, 'property')]"));

    Set<String> foundProperties = new HashSet<String>();

    for(WebElement e : props){
        foundProperties.add(e.getText());
    }

    assertEquals(foundProperties, listOfPropertiesFromApi, "{Properties from API do not match those of website");
```

Comment: Could you sort both lists alphabetically? Or use a LinkedHashSet for both your property lists rather than a regular HashSet http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: Use ArrayList / LinkedList instead of Set so that insertion order will be preserved for comparison.

Comment: @Santoshsarma thanks, this was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

List displays elements in the order they are inserted into the list.
If you are finding that the order is random and not the same as it is appearing in the page, I think you need to investigate how

```
driver.findElements(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='day1']//*[contains(@id, 'property')]"));
```

is fetching the values.

One thing that I can suggest is that if you want this list to be sorted in alphabetic order, then you can use

```
Collections.sort(props)
```

or alternatively use a Custom Comparator to sort using

```
Collections.sort(props, new Comparator() {

<your compare method>


});
```